# Accessing first Nth regex group

Tags: javascript, regex

I have written a `(?!,)(.*?)(?=,)` regex in JavaScript .

This regex returns 20 matching groups, but I want to get first 5 groups.

How can I do this?

Comment: Use some code. What is your language?

Comment: This depends on the language you're using, mostly `$1`, `$2`, ... is used

Comment: Sounds like you want [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Comment: Answered by : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression

Comment: Why can't you split by `,` and then slice it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`match`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp)/[`split`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) and then [`slice`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) the array to get the necessary items:

```js
var re = /[^,]+/g; 
var str = 'word1, word2, word3, word4, word5, word6, word7, word8, word9, word10, word11, word12, ';

alert(str.match(re).slice(0, 5));

var splts = str.split(',').slice(0,5);
alert(splts);
```

Since you are just looking for strings between commas, I suggest using `[^,]+` regex.